# VB.NET Selenium Chromedriver - Access from another Sub

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i have a question about how to access the chromedriver from another sub.

When i click Button1 in my vb.net application, the chromedriver starts and everything is fine.
It starts executing the code and selenium is doing his job (opening page, doing some clicks etc.)
Then it comes to a page where i dont want to type some text and do a click on a button automatically. I want the code execute only if the user press Button2 in my application.

Now my problem:
I dont have access to the chromedriver from the Button2 Sub (because its started and declared on the Button1 Sub)

What i have to do that i can execute code to the chromedriver from the Button2 Sub?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim driver As IWebDriver
        Dim [option1] As New ChromeOptions
        [option1].AddArgument("--log-level=3")
        driver = New ChromeDriver(option1)


        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com")

        'here is some code i execute .. 


    End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        'on button2 click i want to execute this code but i cant because i dont have access to "driver"

        Dim msgbox As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Name("messaging-widget-textarea"))
        msgbox.SendKeys(RichTextBox2.Text)
        msgbox.SendKeys(Keys.Enter)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this  i'm testing and worked 100%

```
Dim options As New ChromeOptions
Dim driver As ChromeDriver

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    options.AddArgument("--log-level=3")
    driver = New ChromeDriver(options)
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com")
    'here is some code i execute .. 
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim msgbox As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Name("messaging-widget-textarea"))
    msgbox.SendKeys(RichTextBox2.Text)
    msgbox.SendKeys(Keys.Enter)

End Sub
```